Noticing negative like and dislike values from the Google Analytics API
I am noticing that I have negative like and dislike values coming from the API. What could be the potential cause?
Data:  {'kind': 'youtubeAnalytics#resultTable', 'columnHeaders': [{'name': 'day', 'columnType': 'DIMENSION', 'dataType': 'STRING'}, {'name': 'views', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'redViews', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'comments', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'likes', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'dislikes', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'shares', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'estimatedMinutesWatched', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'estimatedRedMinutesWatched', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'averageViewDuration', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'averageViewPercentage', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}, {'name': 'annotationClickThroughRate', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}, {'name': 'annotationCloseRate', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}, {'name': 'annotationImpressions', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'annotationClickableImpressions', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'annotationClosableImpressions', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'annotationClicks', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'annotationCloses', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'cardClickRate', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}, {'name': 'cardTeaserClickRate', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}, {'name': 'cardImpressions', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'cardTeaserImpressions', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'cardClicks', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'cardTeaserClicks', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'subscribersGained', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}, {'name': 'subscribersLost', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'INTEGER'}], 'rows': [['2024-09-01', 28, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 1, 97, 29.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1], ['2024-09-02', 32, 3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 29, 0, 55, 18.08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0], ['2024-09-03', 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 60, 11.58, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-04', 40, 7, 0, 4, 0, 1, 94, 16, 142, 42.96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-05', 26, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 39, 1, 91, 34.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-06', 24, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 47, 22, 119, 33.26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-07', 21, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 61, 1, 174, 36.34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-08', 12, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 24, 0, 123, 23.91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-09', 78, 14, 0, 6, 2, 1, 169, 32, 130, 43.31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-10', 18, 4, 0, 2, 0, 0, 28, 0, 94, 66.07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-11', 37, 6, 0, 3, 0, 1, 41, 18, 67, 48.76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], ['2024-09-12', 26, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 31, 5, 72, 14.08, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-13', 21, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 36, 0, 104, 41.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-14', 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 18, 15.53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ['2024-09-15', 12, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 26, 0, 133, 27.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-16', 189, 33, 0, 10, 1, 1, 222, 53, 70, 48.38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-17', 146, 15, 0, 2, 0, 0, 313, 16, 128, 48.39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], ['2024-09-18', 49, 2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 87, 1, 106, 36.37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-19', 253, 88, 2, 2, 5, 0, 72, 15, 17, 32.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-20', 24, 4, 0, 1, -3, 0, 35, 5, 89, 15.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ['2024-09-21', 14, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 33, 0, 143, 15.120000000000001, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-22', 17, 2, 0, -1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 32, 15.329999999999998, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-23', 100, 10, 0, 9, 0, 1, 193, 33, 115, 37.95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0], ['2024-09-24', 92, 19, 0, 0, 0, 1, 54, 4, 35, 27.48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-25', 46, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 72, 1, 94, 32.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ['2024-09-26', 29, 7, 0, -1, 0, 0, 42, 8, 88, 15.42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-27', 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 95, 21.09, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ['2024-09-28', 12, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 48, 19.31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2024-09-29', 17, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 94, 1, 335, 41.24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ['2024-09-30', 63, 9, 0, 2, 0, 1, 260, 33, 247, 52.790000000000006, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]}

Assuming that people who liked a video and then unliked it another day can cause such an event?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
